# what does it mean "we need a demo QR code or AR marker (image) to fully assess your app features."

Tags: ios, qr-code

unfortunately my app rejected and in Resolution Center i found this message " We began the review of your app but are not able to continue because we need a demo QR code or AR marker (image) to fully assess your app features.

Please provide the demo details in the App Review Information section for your app in iTunes Connect or reply to this message with the requested demo information. Please ensure that the information you provide includes any data necessary to demonstrate the functionality of your app features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily pass this by provide an QR or AR code (which can be use to access your app). Just upload that image somewhere, give them a link in "Review note" (you can see this section in the bottom of app's information section).

Re-submit it without re-upload the binary. and then, you can request an expedite for your review process (so you will not have to wait 2 weeks again)

Comment: Thanks Eugene, i didnt undertstand what you mean by Provide AR code?  where i have to upload that image, it is my first time to submit an App. can you a little but specify it? thanks

Comment: can i add Qr code in ( App Video Preview and Screenshots  )? that will be enough?

Comment: Hi John. As i said, you can upload it somewhere (the best is upload to dropbox and send them the link). You can copy the link, go to itunesconnect.apple.com, go to your app, scroll to App Review Information section -> Notes. You can paste your link there and tell them how to use that link to login to your app.